# search default.realm based on a column using Realm browser

Tags: android, ios, realm

I just downloaded the Realm browser, and I can view contents of my Realm file. But how do i search a table based on a particular column.

I feel the search(At the top right) isn't bringing out the result i want.

[image]

Example: lets say i have column: 
**name | height | birthdate | vaccinnated | owner**

I want to search based on **height** on the Realm browser UI.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible yet. There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/issues/28) for simple filters.